# Json-deserialization of List<T> fails: the type requires a JSON array to deserialize correctly

Tags: c#, json-deserialization

I am working on a Xamarin.Forms app in which I need to cache data when no internet connection is available. I am currently using the built-in `Application.Current.Properties` persistence mechanism to persist data, which is working just fine. However, for a more complex object, I am failing to deserialize.

I have the following object Model:

```
public class SPL
{
    public SPL(Point point, Location location)
    {
        Point = point;
        Location = location;
    }

    public Location Location { get; set; }
    public Point Point { get; set; }
}
```

Where `Location` have two properties of type `double` and `Point` has two properties of type `DateTime` and type `double`, respectively.

Through the execution time of the app I continuously persist data in the local cache like so, whenever no internet connection is available

```
SPL spl = new SPL(point, location);
SPLValues.Add(spl);
var serializedSpl = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(SPLValues);
Application.Current.Properties["splvalues"] = serializedSpl;
```

Breaking at the last line and inspecting with the debugger reveals the the data *is* persisted.

When the app goes to sleep I call `Current.SavePropertiesAsync();`. Upon resuming the app I then try to deserialize the local cache like so

```
public List<T> GetCache<T>(string key) where T : class
{
    IDictionary<string, object> properties = Application.Current.Properties;
    if (properties.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(key); // Fails here
        return data;
    }
    return new List<T>();
}
```

Which fails. The exception thrown is

> Unhandled Exception: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: s. Path '', line 0, position 0. occurred

**UPDATE**

As pointed out by JOSEFtw, I was missing a parameter in my deserialization call, so it now looks like this instead: `var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(properties[key]);`

After fixing this, I now encounter this error:

> Unhandled Exception: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[CacheDemo.Models.SPL]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
>   To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
>   Path 'Location', line 1, position 12. occurred

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should Deserialize

```
properties[key]
```

instead of

```
key
```

Like this

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(properties[key]);
```

Comment: Thanks, that definitely helped the process a bit along - can't believe I missed that. But now I encounter a new error. I'll update the question.

Comment: You should not change your question, everyones answers will be outdated then. Ask a new question instead.

Comment: But the error message is rather clear imo, you are trying to deserialize something into a list that isn't a list/collection/array. And it would really help if you posted the actual JSON...

Comment: Duly noted, apologize. I agree, it does seem obvious. I have posted an answer below as I seem to have solved the issue somewhat magically.

Answer (score 0):

I have actually solved the issue, but it is not what I expected. I am reluctant to post this as an answer as it does not really tie into the actual error. However, it seemed that the `Properties` contained an empty `Location` object (it had no properties) and thus upon deserialization it failed. Which in itself is odd to me, as I would expect it to just return an empty object, then? I can't gather how the `Location` object was written to disk as being empty, and running `.Clear()` on `Properties` did not seem to remove it. What worked was to deploy the app to a physical device, and suddenly the error vanished. Inspecting the `Properties` cache using the debugger on the physical device revealed that the empty `Location` object had been removed, and this is why I am assuming that the empty `Location` object was at fault.